# What is the complexity of hash_set::size() in C++ STL?

Tags: c++, stl

That is, the computational complexity. Does it have to count all the elements? Does it depend on implementation? The SGI spec doesn't guarantee anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current C++ standard doesn't specify a hash_set, so yes, 
it is implementation dependent. I find it a bit hard to imagine an
acceptable implementation for which this wouldn't be 
constant time, however.

Answer (score 0):

Unspecified, as far as I know, but probably constant time.  The Microsoft implementation is constant time.